# Is there a way to put tabs inside a drawer in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I currently am new in Flutter and is looking for help for a feature I'm trying to implement. I have too many information in my drawer currently so I am trying to put tabs inside the drawer so people can access different kinds of information inside the drawer. I photoshopped a picture to show the idea that I have in my head. [Drawer with Tab Pictures shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy5qr.jpg). So far, I've tried the DefaultTabController but couldn't get it to work so if anyone has any other ideas or a different way of approaching it I would be really grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can wrap `DefaultTabController` with `Drawer` 
code snippet

```
return Scaffold(
      ...
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.black12,
                child: TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "First"),
                      Tab(text: "Second"),
                      Tab(text: "Third"),
                    ]),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: TabBarView(children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text("First Body"),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Second Body"),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Third Body"),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child: Text('Drawer Header'),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.black12,
                child: TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(text: "First"),
                      Tab(text: "Second"),
                      Tab(text: "Third"),
                    ]),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: TabBarView(children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text("First Body"),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Second Body"),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Text("Third Body"),
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```